# How to add inertia to widget rotated by swipe offset? (add momentum)

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

For example, I have a widget which is rotated on user swipe using variable `dragoffset += details.offset.dx`;

How is it possible to add inertia to rotation when swipe ended? E.g. when you release your finger, and object continues to rotate with descending velocity -- just like ListView normally behaves.

Here's some boilerplate code as example:

```
Widget rotatedWidget() {
    double fingerOffset = 0.0;
    return GestureDetector(
        onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
          setState((){ 
             fingerOffset += details.delta.dx; 
          });
        },
        onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
           /// some code to add inertia
        },
        child: Transform.rotate(
          angle: offset,
          child: Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.blue),
        ));
  }
```

[image: illustration]

Comment: see `AnimationController.fling()` method (or `animateWith()` to be more flexible as you can use any `Simulation`)

Comment: @pskink I'm sorry, it's unclear to me how to use it in this case, since I don't use AnimationController to rotate widget - I use the value of swipe offset.

Comment: use `onPanEnd: (d) => ctrl.animateWith(FrictionSimulation(0.05, ctrl.value, d.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx / 100)),
` - here you have only 3 parameters and they seem to be meaningful

Comment: @pskink Okay, that's a lot better! Looks like a perfect solution to my problem. Could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) for this solution.

(Edit: Adding physics package import and `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` to the class's inheritance as it's needed for an AnimationController to be vsynced to the current class)

```
import 'package:flutter/physics.dart';

class RotateState extends State<Rotate> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

 AnimationController ctrl;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ctrl = AnimationController.unbounded(vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanUpdate: (d) => ctrl.value += d.delta.dx / 100,
      onPanEnd: (d) {
        ctrl.animateWith(
          FrictionSimulation(
              0.05, // <- the bigger this value, the less friction is applied
              ctrl.value,
              d.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx / 100 // <- Velocity of inertia
          ));
        },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('RotatedBox'),
        ),
        body: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: ctrl,
          builder: (ctx, w) {
            return Center(
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: ctrl.value,
                child: Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.blue),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: btw, if you want to stop at some fixed place (for example at some multiple 30 degree angles - i mean 0, 30, 60, 90 etc) you would need `SpringSimulation` instead of `FrictionSimulation`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212927/discussion-between-emvaized-and-pskink).